# slam_gmapping tutorial

Tags: navigation, map-saver, tutorial, slam-gmapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working through the [Robot Setup of the Navigation Tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup) and the [slam_gmapping tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/slam_gmapping/Tutorials/MappingFromLoggedData).

I have downloaded the bagfile and ran slam_gmapping.  I did not run the whole bagfile, because it was so long.

When I run map_saver, I get the following:

```
Waiting for the map
```

How do I get around this?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204813/slam_gmapping-tutorial/) by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on ROS Answers with karma: 323 on 2015-03-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured it out.

slam_gmapping must still be running when you run the map_saver.

---

Originally posted by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) with karma: 323 on 2015-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1